# Unable to consume messages from AWS SQS DLQ but can consume from main SQS queue

Tags: kotlin, amazon-sqs

I have two separate message listener classes written in Kotlin to listen to two separate AWS SQS queues (one is main SQS queue and another is Dead Letter Queue (DLQ)).
The problem is that the message listener for DLQ is unable to consume the messages from its DLQ. This is a tricky problem because my listener code of DLQ is absolutely correct and can consume the messages from other SQS queues but not for this DLQ particularly. I tested its working functionality by replacing DLQ name by the main queue name. There are messages on DLQ as well. By the way both queues are standard queues on AWS (not FIFO).

Here is the code snippet where I'm initializing the SQS connection:-

```
@PostConstruct
fun init() {
    try {
        if (enableCalmQueue) {
            initializeListeners("$podName-${Util.MAIN_QUEUE}", mainQueueListener)
            initializeListeners("$podName-${Util.DLQ}", dlqListener)
            LOG.info("Initialized SQS Queue Response Handler")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        LOG.warn("Failed to Initialize response handler due to ${e.message}")
    }
}
   private fun initializeListeners(queueName: String, messageListener: MessageListener) {
        val connection = getSqsConnectionObject()
        val session = connection.createSession(false, SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE)
        val consumer = session.createConsumer(session.createQueue(queueName))
        consumer.messageListener = messageListener
        connection.start()
        LOG.info("Initialized $messageListener for $queueName")
    }

  private fun getSqsConnectionObject(): SQSConnection {
        val connectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory(
                ProviderConfiguration(),
                AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient()
        )
        return connectionFactory.createConnection()
    }
```

DLQ Listener:-

```
@Named("dlqListener")
class DeadLetterQueueListener : MessageListener {

    @Value("\${pod_name}")
    private val podName: String = "dev"

    @Inject
    private lateinit var tradeStatusService: TradeStatusService

    companion object {
        private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeadLetterQueueListener::class.java)
    }

    override fun onMessage(message: Message?) {
        try {
            if (message is TextMessage) {
                LOG.info("Received message ${message.text} in Dead Letter Queue Listener " +
                        "with jmsMessageId: ${message.jmsMessageID}")
                if(message.getStringProperty(Util.QUEUE_NAME) == "$podName-${Util.MAIN_QUEUE}") {
                    message.acknowledge()
                    val jsonMessage = message.text
                    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
                    val externalTradeInputs = objectMapper.readValue(jsonMessage, ExternalTradeInputs::class.java)
                    val tradeStatusData = TradeStatusData().apply {
                        this.tradeBookingId = externalTradeInputs.tradeBookingId
                        this.statusDateTime = Date()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LOG.error("Error processing in Dead Letter Queue Listener with : ${e.message}")
        }
    }
}
```

Like I mentioned, this **dlqListener** works fine if I pass the main queue name but not DLQ queue name.
I tried to debug a lot but could not find anything concrete. Both main and DLQ exists in AWS. I suspect something some wrong in the way DLQ has been configured but to my best I have verified but nothing found any issues over there.
I would really appreciate if someone can give me some reference or hints about its root cause.

Comment: Is it perhaps your IAM permissions? Do your creds have access to both queues?

Comment: just curious to know if it would be related to IAM then how come I'm able to connect to the DLQ queue successfully (connection is success for both queue) but I do not get any messages consumed or listener do not listen to any messages in that specific DLQ?

Comment: Try creating 2 new queues and try the same code with those 2